# In Tensorflow I can't use any MultiRNNCell instance in dynamic decode, but a single RNNCell instance can work on it

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, seq2seq

I make a seq2seq model using tensorflow and meet a problem that my program throws an error when I use MultiRNNCell in tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode.

The problem happens over here:

```
defw_rnn=tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([
            tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=self.FLAGS.rnn_units,
            initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer)
            for _ in range(self.FLAGS.rnn_layer_size)])

        training_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(inputs=decoder_inputs,
                                                            sequence_length=self.decoder_targets_length,
                                                            time_major=False)

        training_decoder = \
            tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
                defw_rnn, training_helper,
                encoder_final_state,
                output_layer)
        training_decoder_output, _, training_decoder_output_length = \
            tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
                training_decoder,
                  impute_finished=True,
                  maximum_iterations=self.FLAGS.max_len)
```

When I run this code,the console shows this Error message:

> `C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe E:/PycharmProject/cikm_transport/CIKM/CIKM/translate_model/train.py
>   WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py:417: calling reverse_sequence (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) with seq_dim is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   seq_dim is deprecated, use seq_axis instead
>   WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py:432: calling reverse_sequence (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) with batch_dim is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   batch_dim is deprecated, use batch_axis instead
>   encoder_final_state shpe
>   LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'encoder/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/while/Exit_5:0' shape=(?, 24) dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 'encoder/bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/while/Exit_6:0' shape=(?, 24) dtype=float32>)
>   decoder_inputs shape before embedded
>   (128, 10)
>   decoder inputs shape after embedded
>   (128, 10, 5)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "E:/PycharmProject/cikm_transport/CIKM/CIKM/translate_model/train.py", line 14, in <module>
>       len(embedding_matrix['embedding'][0]))
>     File "E:\PycharmProject\cikm_transport\CIKM\CIKM\translate_model\model.py", line 109, in __init__
>       maximum_iterations=self.FLAGS.max_len)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\seq2seq\python\ops\decoder.py", line 323, in dynamic_decode
>       swap_memory=swap_memory)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3209, in while_loop
>       result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2941, in BuildLoop
>       pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2878, in _BuildLoop
>       body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3179, in <lambda>
>       body = lambda i, lv: (i + 1, orig_body(*lv))
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\seq2seq\python\ops\decoder.py", line 266, in body
>       decoder_finished) = decoder.step(time, inputs, state)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\seq2seq\python\ops\basic_decoder.py", line 137, in step
>       cell_outputs, cell_state = self._cell(inputs, state)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 232, in __call__
>       return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 329, in __call__
>       outputs = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 703, in __call__
>       outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1325, in call
>       cur_inp, new_state = cell(cur_inp, cur_state)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 339, in __call__
>       *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py", line 329, in __call__
>       outputs = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 703, in __call__
>       outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn_cell_impl.py", line 846, in call
>       (c_prev, m_prev) = state
>     File "C:\Users\TopView\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 436, in __iter__
>       "Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not "
>   TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.`
>
> `Process finished with exit code 1`

But when I change the instance of `defw_rnn`, make it a single RNN instance like LSTMCell, the Error disappears:

```
defw_rnn=tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=self.FLAGS.rnn_units,
            initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer)
```

And the code works well. However, I've found  that most of the code about seq2seq model on the Internet using MultiRNNCell and they also use tensorflow, so it really confuse me that what is wrong with my program.

Here is the entire code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Seq2SeqModel(object):
    def bw_fw_rnn(self): 
        with tf.name_scope("forward_rnn"):
            fw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([
                tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=self.FLAGS.rnn_units,
                                        initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer) for _ in
                range(self.FLAGS.rnn_layer_size)])
            fw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(fw, output_keep_prob=self.FLAGS.keep_prob)
        with tf.name_scope("backward_rnn"):
            bw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([
                tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=self.FLAGS.rnn_units,
                                        initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer) for _ in
                range(self.FLAGS.rnn_layer_size)])
            bw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(bw, output_keep_prob=self.FLAGS.keep_prob)
        return (fw, bw)

    def decode_inputs_preprocess(self, data, id_matrix):
        ending=tf.strided_slice(data,[0,0],[self.batch_size,-1],[1,1])
        decoder_input=tf.concat([tf.fill([self.batch_size,1],id_matrix.index('<go>')),ending],1)
        return decoder_input

    def __init__(self, FLAGS, english_id_matrix, spanish_id_matrix, english_vocab_size,spanish_vocab_size, embedding_size):
        self.FLAGS = FLAGS
        self.english_vocab_size = english_vocab_size
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size
        self.encoder_input = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, self.FLAGS.max_len], dtype=tf.int32, name='encoder_inputs')
        self.decoder_targets = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, self.FLAGS.max_len], dtype=tf.int32, name='decoder_targets')
        self.encoder_input_sequence_length = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32, name='encoder_inputs_length')
        self.decoder_targets_length = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32, name='decoder_targets_length')
        self.batch_size = self.FLAGS.batch_size
        with tf.name_scope('embedding_look_up'):
            spanish_embeddings = tf.Variable(
                tf.random_uniform([english_vocab_size,
                                   embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),
                dtype=tf.float32)
            english_embeddings = tf.Variable(
                tf.random_uniform([english_vocab_size,
                                   embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),
                dtype=tf.float32)
            self.spanish_embeddings_inputs = tf.placeholder(
                dtype=tf.float32, shape=[english_vocab_size, embedding_size],
                name='spanish_embeddings_inputs')
            self.english_embeddings_inputs = tf.placeholder(
                dtype=tf.float32, shape=[english_vocab_size, embedding_size],
                name='spanish_embeddings_inputs')
            self.spanish_embeddings_inputs_op = spanish_embeddings.assign(self.spanish_embeddings_inputs)
            self.english_embeddings_inputs_op = english_embeddings.assign(self.english_embeddings_inputs)
            encoder_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(spanish_embeddings, self.encoder_input)

        with tf.name_scope('encoder'):
            enfw_rnn, enbw_rnn = self.bw_fw_rnn()
            encoder_outputs, encoder_final_state = \
                tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(enfw_rnn, enbw_rnn, encoder_inputs
                                                , sequence_length=self.encoder_input_sequence_length, dtype=tf.float32)
            print("encoder_final_state shpe")
            # final_state_c=tf.concat([encoder_final_state[0][-1].c,encoder_final_state[1][-1].c],1)
            # final_state_h=tf.concat([encoder_final_state[0][-1].h,encoder_final_state[1][-1].h],1)
            # encoder_final_state=tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(c=final_state_c,
             #                                        h=final_state_h)
            encoder_final_state=encoder_final_state[0][-1]
            print(encoder_final_state)

        with tf.name_scope('dense_layer'):
            output_layer = tf.layers.Dense(english_vocab_size,
                                           kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(
                                               mean=0.0, stddev=0.1
                                           ))
        # training decoder
        with tf.name_scope('decoder'), tf.variable_scope('decode'):
            decoder_inputs=self.decode_inputs_preprocess(self.decoder_targets,english_id_matrix)
            print('decoder_inputs shape before embedded')
            print(decoder_inputs.shape)
            decoder_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(english_embeddings,decoder_inputs)
            print('decoder inputs shape after embedded')
            print(decoder_inputs.shape)
            defw_rnn=tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([
                tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=self.FLAGS.rnn_units,
                initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer)
                for _ in range(self.FLAGS.rnn_layer_size)])

            training_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(inputs=decoder_inputs,
                                                                sequence_length=self.decoder_targets_length,
                                                                time_major=False)

            training_decoder = \
                tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
                    defw_rnn, training_helper,
                    encoder_final_state,
                    output_layer)
            training_decoder_output, _, training_decoder_output_length = \
                tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
                    training_decoder,
                      impute_finished=True,
                      maximum_iterations=self.FLAGS.max_len)
            training_logits = tf.identity(training_decoder_output.rnn_output, 'logits')
            print("training logits shape")
            print(training_logits.shape)
        # predicting decoder
        with tf.variable_scope('decode', reuse=True):
            start_tokens = tf.tile(tf.constant([english_id_matrix.index('<go>')], dtype=tf.int32),
                                   [self.batch_size], name='start_tokens')
            predicting_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper(english_embeddings,
                                                                         start_tokens,
                                                                         english_id_matrix.index('<eos>'))
            predicting_decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(defw_rnn,
                                                                 predicting_helper,
                                                                 encoder_final_state,
                                                                 output_layer)
            predicting_decoder_output, _, predicting_decoder_output_length =\
                tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
                predicting_decoder,
                impute_finished=True,
                maximum_iterations=self.FLAGS.max_len)

            self.predicting_logits = tf.identity(predicting_decoder_output.sample_id, name='predictions')
            print("predicting logits shape")
            print(self.predicting_logits.shape)
        masks = tf.sequence_mask(self.decoder_targets_length, self.FLAGS.max_len, dtype=tf.float32, name='masks')
        with tf.variable_scope('optimization'), tf.name_scope('optimization'):
            # Loss
            self.cost = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(training_logits, self.decoder_targets, masks)
            # Optimizer
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.FLAGS.alpha)
            # Gradient Clipping
            gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(self.cost)
            capped_gradients = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -5., 5.), var) for grad, var in gradients if grad is not None]
            self.train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gradients)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well……I've figured out.The problem happened because I only sent the final state of the encoder to a decoder.